# What is the limit of $ n \cdot 0 $ as n approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

What is the limit of $ n \cdot 0 $ as $n$ approaches infinity?
Is it undefined or is it just $0$?

Comment: What happens when you apply the definition of a limit in this case?

Comment: the indetermination is when  you have $n\cdot a_n$ and $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$n\cdot 0 = 0$ for all naturals.
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot 0 = \lim_{n\to \infty} 0 = 0$$

Comment: +1, That what it's all about.